# NodeJS / VueJS in docker-compose - local version works fine, but on server images not loading

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I built a webapp with dynamic image loading. The project is deployed in a docker-compose.
Nginx as reverse Proxy, NodeJS with the app as frontend with "npm run serve" to provide Hotreload, due to the dynamic image changes, and a php backend container.

When I start the compose locally on my computer everything works fine and every image is loading.
When I start the compose on my server, the images won't load, but there is no error in my proxy, frontend or anywhere else.
My browser even says HTTP Code 200 for the images. Also static images work fine.

The images are loaded with the following method:

```
getImages(set) {

  let path
  let imageList = []

  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.files.children[set].children).length; i++) {
    path = require('../assets/images/Category1/' + this.files.children[set].name + '/' + this.files.children[set].children[i].name)
    imageList[i] = path
  }
  return imageList
}
```

Where does the webpack server "save" the compiled website? As the images get a name extension, they must be saved somewhere else, I guess.
I wanted to look, if there might be a problem with this, but currently I don't know where to find the issue.
The only thing I had to change for the server is:

```
devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
}
```

But even with this change it works locally on my computer.

Also on my server there is another reverse proxy to use subdomains, but as I can reach the site and don't get errors in my logs, I guess, that proxy is working fine.

A small image to show how the server works and the red part is this project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IregD.jpg

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    container_name: project.exam.pl_proxy
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=project.exam.pl
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=project.exam.pl
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mail@exam.pl
    expose:
      - '80'
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
 
  backend:
    container_name: project.exam.pl_backend
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    hostname: backend
    volumes:
    - ./backend:/var/www/html
 
  frontend:
    container_name: project.exam.pl_frontend
    hostname: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /srv/www/cloud.exam.pl/data/user/files/Website/:/app/src/assets/images/
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - cron
 
  cron:
    container_name: project.exam.pl_cron
    build:
      context: ./cron
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /srv/www/cloud.exam.pl/data/user/files/Website/:/app/src/assets/images/
```

frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
 
# creating app dir and using as workdir
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
 
# install python for indexing images
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
 
# copying dependencies and installing via npm
COPY package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
 
# run at start of container after build
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT npm run serve
```

proxy default.conf:

```
server {
 
    listen                  80;
    server_name             project.exam.pl;
 
    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass          http://frontend:8080;
 
        location ~* \.php$ {
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass    backend:9000;
        }
    }
}
```

Where could this problem come from?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the details required in the question itself, not behind links?  In the local environment, are you overriding the image's contents with `volumes:`; and if you delete that setting, does it behave the same way as in the remote environment?

Comment: I edited the question. Well in local and on remote I override the images content with a volume linked to my cloud. I tried copying the images and removed the volume, but still the same problem. No errors, but still not loading.